# Chrome xls file type is empty strings

Tags: excel, file, google-chrome, mime-types, xls

I am using the the uploaded file `type` property to determine its file type (AKA mime-type).

`<input type="file" class="file-upload" accept=".xls,.xlsx,.pdf,.doc,.docx">`

**Issue:**

Uploading an `.xls` file results in a file type of empty strings `""`.

**Expected Behavior:**

An `.xls` should have a file type (AKA mime-type) of `application/vnd.ms-excel`.

**JSFiddle Demo Link**

http://jsfiddle.net/DevMai90/2t0f1mc9/103/

This issue is only occurring in Chrome. Safari and Firefox renders the correct file type.

Has anyone else run into this issue? Is there some known compatibility issue with uploading .xls files and Chrome?

Comment: Checking mime-type in terminal correctly renders  `application/vnd.ms-excel`.
`file --mime-type -b test-file.xls`

Answer (score 1):

There is an ongoing ticket filed with Chromium. While they are aware of the issue, they currently do not have any plans to review how mime-types are evaluated.

Reponse from Chromium member.

> Eventually I do want to re-evaluate how we determine the mime type for File objects as reported to the web. But no concrete plans/schedule at this point.

Chromium Bug Link --> https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=155455